# Are there any details about magic academy / courses in SR?

Tags: magic, shadowrun

As there is quite a lot of background info out for shadowrun regarding how people life there and what they do and can't do, what they buy and can't buy, ... I'm wondering if there is also some info somewhere about magic academies and magic courses held at universities.

Thus how life is there and how they go about doing things. Is any info located about this in some of the books?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Street Grimoire](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/131832/Shadowrun-Street-Grimoire)?

It has a lot of content about magic in the academic life, which i wont paste it all here but will quote only the most relevant paragraph (pg 16):

> Universities present the most consistent career path
>   for magicians, but they create a problem because magicians
>   often end up with the same flavor as their university,
>   taking away from the individuality of the form.
>   Overall there are Associate, Bachelors, Masters, and
>   Doctoral level degrees conferred in Thaumaturgy. The
>   organization of Thaumaturgy colleges has sparked debate
>   how magic should be taught. Traditionally speaking,
>   Thaumaturgy is considered a science at the university
>   level. Magicians construct spell formulae and follow
>   traditions rooted in reason. Newer programs relate magic
>   more closely to schools of art, treating the traditions
>   as individual art forms and conferring Thaumaturgic Arts
>   degrees at the Bachelors and Masters levels.